# How to compare a int variable with a function that returns a int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make code( that I stole) output the Fibonacci sequence and I'm having trouble letting the function Terms be able to compare to an variable. I know this is messy code but I like 3 days into python so I don't know what to do.

```
# first two terms
n1, n2 = 0, 1
count = 0


# Asks amount of terms to be generated 
def Terms():
   while True:
        nterms = (input("How many terms? "))
        if nterms.isdigit():
            nterms= int(nterms)
            if nterms > 0:
               break
            else:
               print("0")
        else:
            print("Please choose an number that is able to be used")
   return nterms
Terms()
# Calls Terms then generates
print(int(Terms))
def Fibonacci():
   # first two terms
   n1, n2 = 0, 1
   count = 0
   Terms()
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   while count < Terms: #Problem right here TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'function'
      print(n1)
      nth = n1 + n2
     # update values
      n1 = n2
      n2 = nth
      count += 1
Fibonacci()
```

I tried making terms an int but it still doesn't work

Comment: If you want to use the value returned by a function later, save is as a variable: `some_var = Terms()` then you can use it `while count < some_var`

Comment: Also don't give functions an uppercase letter. Python has naming conventions, stick to those: classes use UpperCamelCase, functions and variables use lower_snake_case. And as non-official convention, make your functions after what they do. So not `Terms` but `get_user_input` and not `Fibonacci` but `calculate_fibonacci_number` or something similar. And _even though_ you're storing your terms globally, make them an argument to that fibonacci function. Get into the habit of making sure functions get all the values they need from their arguments. Don't rely on globals.

Comment: I have no idea what that all means but I'll keep that in mind if I figure what those mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few small things. So you called the different functions from a few places. So I removed a few calls and put returnvalue from Terms() in variable terms, and then it worked.

```py
# first two terms
n1, n2 = 0, 1
count = 0


# Asks amount of terms to be generated 
def Terms():
   while True:
        nterms = (input("How many terms? "))
        if nterms.isdigit():
            nterms= int(nterms)
            if nterms > 0:
               break
            else:
               print("0")
        else:
            print("Please choose an number that is able to be used")
   return nterms

# Calls Terms then generates
def Fibonacci():
   # first two terms
   n1, n2 = 0, 1
   count = 0
   terms = Terms() # This is the new variable
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   while count < terms: # And using the variable here
      print(n1)
      nth = n1 + n2
     # update values
      n1 = n2
      n2 = nth
      count += 1
Fibonacci()
```

Comment: That was all I had to do? :( 
Thank you btw

Answer (score 2):

The fix is probably

```
while count < Terms():
```

The error message tells you explicitly that you may not compare to a function (but to a function result). (But after this fix, you will run into another problem...)

---

An alternative implementation:

```
# Query the number of terms
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("How many terms [integer > 1] ? "))
        if n > 1:
            break
    except:
        pass
    print("Invalid input, try again")

# Output the desired number of terms
f0, f1= 0, 1
for i in range(n):
    print("F"+str(i)+" =", f0)
    f0, f1= f1, f0+f1
```